# Suggestion: Delete [data]-tag, or is there something more to it, I don't see?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just saw there is a `data` tag around and do not understand what the possible meaning of this tag is and, therefore, would recommend to delete it.

[Right now, there are 8 questions with this tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data). As far as I see it, they could all survive either without it or with some other tag (e.g., `missing-data` which is non-existent so far).
In my understanding [data] is actually meaningless. By far most of the questions are related to data in any type so it is just useless to put a [data] tag on them.

I hope it is okay to post a new question, as I didn't find another question to put this topic.

Comment: I think that this is a reasonable suggestion.  Let's see if others agree before I delete it.

Comment: Makes sense....

Comment: I agree. dataset would be a good replacement for some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After unanimous agreement I deleted the `data` tag from the following questions and, where it seemed reasonable, exchanged it with other tags.

[Free Dataset Resources?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145/free-dataset-resources)

[Poisson regression with large data: is it wrong to change the unit of measurement?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270/poisson-regression-with-large-data-is-it-wrong-to-change-the-unit-of-measurement)

[Where is a good place to find survey results?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641/where-is-a-good-place-to-find-survey-results)

[Best ways to aggregate and analyze data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645/best-way-to-aggregate-and-analyze-data)

[Dataset for multi class perceptron](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/715/dataset-for-multi-class-perceptron)

[Intuition for higher moments in circular statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/intuition-for-higher-moments-in-circular-statistics)

[Techniques for Handling Incomplete/Missing Data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/techniques-for-handling-incomplete-missing-data)

[Test for Poolability of Individual Data Series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1822/test-for-poolability-of-individual-data-series)